# Improving fluency without being able to talk to other people?

Tags: accent

I am looking for tips/tricks to improve English fluency without talking to natives. I do speak English on a daily basis, however I speak English to a lot of other non-native speakers.

I am Dutch and have a slight Dutch accent. This bothers me but I have not been able to focus on getting a better accent going.

Would repeating certain things or reading out loud have any effect? Or would listening to audiobooks help?
All the books, tv and movies I read/watch are English already and I type in English most of my day.

Comment: Related (but not a duplicate): http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/1119/ There is some advice in the answers to that question that I think would also apply to your question, even though it's a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

It is apparent that you are already using English with a high level of expertise. There is probably little that can be done to improve your accent that you are not already doing. The only way to refine your accent is to interact with native speakers over a long period of time.

Which English accent do you want to have? There is a vast difference between the accents of people of different ages, classes and regions even within Britain.

Perhaps you should reflect on why your accent bothers you. Your accent is probably already closer to received pronunciation that a speaker of American English, and doesn't interfere with intelligibility. If that is the case, how important is accent anyway?

Answer (score 0):

I think feedback is essential, I don't see how you can modify your capabilities without spotting what you are doing wrong.

Can you **hear** your accent? That is, if you record yourself repeating a phrase by a native speaker and compare your pronunciation can you hear a difference? My guess is that you will be able to hear this, and in effect provide your own feedback and modify accordingly.

If not then I think you need feedback from another person or coach. I don't see why you exclude the possibility to talk to natives. With Skype and the like this need not mean actually being in the same place as a friendly coach.

I observe that when I return to my native Yorkshire my english accent reverts to its Northern roots, I am imitating the people I hear around me. So I think finding a way to interact with native speakers may help, but I think finding a coach would have more benefit. Are there no expats near you who could spend some time over a beer?