# How to improve English speaking

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-usage, american-english, learning-methods

I am not a native English speaker. I have been preparing for the IELTS exam since last six months. I can write English properly. But I cannot speak English fluently. I make several mistakes while speaking. I cannot make compound sentences while speaking. Sometimes I start stammering and repeat same word again and again. In addition, sometimes I fail to transfer my thought properly. Like I construct a sentence but without exact meaning. Like if I want to answer the question "Disadvantage of airports" I say, `airports are noise/airports create noise.` But I think those sentences are not meaningful. I should say `The planes create noise while take-off`.

Another example is: I want to answer a job-related question and I said, `There are some jobs which have a huge salary.` But I think I should say `There are some jobs which has to offer a high salary to its employees if it is done by human labour.`

Can anyone suggest me after seeing my examples how could I improve my English? What is my exact problem? Why cannot I speak precisely?

Comment: This might be helpful: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/how-to-get-rid-of-mistakes-in-spoken-english.

Comment: Everybody makes "mistakes" when speaking. All people sometimes speak unclearly (includinga all native speakers) I don't think there is any specific advice that you will get here.  You don't yet have good judgement about what is idiomatic: You "incorrect" examples are no worse, and in some cases better than your "correct" examples. Apart from "relax, enjoy and practice" there isn't any special advice.  Have you talked to your teacher?

Comment: I learn by myself. So I am seeking some advice. Can you please refer me Which incorrect sentences better than my correct sentence?

Comment: Well, "There are some jobs which has to offer..."  The verb "has" doesn't agree with the implied subject "jobs". If you are learning on your own, who do you practice talking with? You probably just need to get used to making mistakes and carrying on, but to do that you need to have the opportunity to talk.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of mistakes in spoken English?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/1119/how-to-get-rid-of-mistakes-in-spoken-english)

Comment: @JamesK I talk then record it. Then hear it again and again and try to rectify my errors.